# Getting record from database that has empty field

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following lines of code to retrieve records from a database:

```
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname; charset=utf8;", $username, $password);
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM usa WHERE code = :code AND window1 = :oldrepeat AND spare <> :americinn  AND  url IS NOT NULL ORDER BY user ASC");
       $sql->execute(array(':code' => $code, ':oldrepeat' => $oldrepeat, ':americinn' =>$americinn));
        /*** fetch the results ***/
  $result = $sql->fetch();
```

Amongst other criteria, this query is supposed to return records that only have some content in the field called `url`, but this is not happening. It is returning records that also have an empty `url` field.

I assume that I am doing something fundamentally wrong but cannot see what it is.

Can anyone shed some light please?

Best wishes

Comment: `NULL` != empty btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, write your query in following way:

```
SELECT * FROM usa WHERE code = :code AND window1 = :oldrepeat AND spare <> :americinn  AND  !ISNULL(url) ORDER BY user ASC
```

`ISNULL` is an inbuilt MySQL function that checks if value of a column is null. By using `!` (negation), you will get only required rows.

In case if a column has blank value, you can try `url!=''`.